# My Arduino Serial Monitor is Displaying My IMU Gyro/accel board data as Gibberish

Tags: windows-8, serial-port, arduino, arduino-uno

I am running windows 8(64) and am using Arduino Uno for the first time. I downloaded the IDE and plugged in my arduino. I'm using a IMU 6050 Accelerometer Gyroscope Breakout Board and am using the first MPU6050 DMP6 example program to test it out. I open up the serial monitor and instead of displaying the text like it should, it only displays a line of weird symbols(cross,box, y with a dot over it, Germanic alphabet letters) and then nothing else. I am brand new to ardruino and can't figure out what to do. I checked the Uno driver and everything is fine. All the arduino files are downloaded, I have downloaded both the MPU library as well as the I2C library. The Uno is blinking, the data is coming through (I think) for some reason its just not displaying right. I have been searching all over the web for days now and I can't find anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a baud rate mismatch issue. Try to change the baud rate from the drop-down and make sure that it matches the rate passed to Serial.begin in your sketch.

Comment: It does that is why the problem is very unsettling to me